# Placing Line over ItemsContol the IsMouseOver property is overwritten in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Canvas`, which displaying Lines from an `ObservableCollection<T>`, and also 2 lines after the left and right mouse is clicked on the `Canvas`, and a temp `Line`, which is always under the mouse pointer. Here is the code:

```
<Canvas Height="100" Margin="5" Background="Transparent" Name="MeasureCanvas"
                MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" MouseEnter="Canvas_MouseEnter"
                MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove" MouseLeave="Canvas_MouseLeave">

            <ItemsControl Name="Lines" ItemsSource="{Binding SnapLines}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas>
                            <Thumb DragDelta="onDragDelta" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
                                <Thumb.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Line Style="{StaticResource LeftLineStyle}" MouseEnter="Line_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Line_MouseLeave" Name="LeftLine" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Thumb.Template>
                            </Thumb>
                            <Thumb DragDelta="onDragDelta" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
                                <Thumb.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Line Style="{StaticResource RightLineStyle}" MouseEnter="Line_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Line_MouseLeave" Name="RightLine" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Thumb.Template>
                            </Thumb>
                            <arrow:ArrowLine Style="{StaticResource ConnectingLineStyle}" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <Line Style="{StaticResource MeasureLine1Style}"   />
            <Line Style="{StaticResource MeasureLine2Style}" />
            <arrow:ArrowLine Style="{StaticResource MeasureArrowStyle}"   />

            <Line Style="{StaticResource MeasureTempLineStyle}" />
        </Canvas>
```

The Lines:

```
<Style x:Key="MeasureLine1Style" TargetType="Line">
    <Setter Property="X1" Value="{Binding MeasureLine1.X}" />
    <Setter Property="X2" Value="{Binding MeasureLine1.X}" />
    <Setter Property="Y1" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Y2" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MeasureLine1.X}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="MeasureLine2Style" TargetType="Line">
    <Setter Property="X1" Value="{Binding MeasureLine2.X}" />
    <Setter Property="X2" Value="{Binding MeasureLine2.X}" />
    <Setter Property="Y1" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Y2" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MeasureLine2.X}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="MeasureTempLineStyle" TargetType="Line">
    <Setter Property="X1" Value="{Binding MeasureTemp.X}" />
    <Setter Property="X2" Value="{Binding MeasureTemp.X}" />
    <Setter Property="Y1" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Y2" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource SelectedLineGreen}" />
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />

    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MeasuringPlacingLine}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And also the displayed `Lines`, from the `ItemsControl`:

```
    <Setter Property="X1" Value="{Binding Point1.X}" />
    <Setter Property="X2" Value="{Binding Point1.X}" />
    <Setter Property="Y1" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Y2" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding PointMargin}" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="White" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="20" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource LineGreen}" />
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Point1.X}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="RightLineStyle" TargetType="Line">
    <Setter Property="X1" Value="{Binding Point2.X}" />
    <Setter Property="X2" Value="{Binding Point2.X}" />
    <Setter Property="Y1" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Y2" Value="200" />

    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding PointMargin}" />
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Point2.X}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="White" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="20" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource LineGreen}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

So when the user hover over the placed `Line` from the `ItemsControl`, it will glow, and the user drag around with the `DragDelta`.

My problem is, this only works if I comment out the following Line:

```
<Line Style="{StaticResource MeasureTempLineStyle}" />
```

When the Temp Line is showing, the temp line is getting the `IsMouseOver` property, so the placed `Line` from the `ItemsControl` doesn't receive this. See on the pictures:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [IsHitTestVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to false on your temp line. This effectively makes it invisible to the mouse.